# Eclipse incorrectly giving EL syntax error

Tags: eclipse, el

I have the following EL expression:

```
${fn:escapeXml(fn:replace(response.distHeadline, "'", "\\'"))
```

Basically is double escapes all apostrophes within "response.distHeadline", then Xml escapes the distHeadline after that.  I am doing this because I am passing this to a JavaScript method.  But in Eclipse it gives an EL syntax error on the first quote and then when I auto-format (Control+Shift+F) if breaks and moves the remaining equation to the next line.

```
${fn:escapeXml(fn:replace(response.distHeadline, "
'", "\\'"))
```

So when I publish the page the equation does not work.  If I manually keep the equation all on one line it works properly.

How do I prevent Eclipse from thinking there is an error or prevent Eclipse from breaking this equation into two lines.

Complete tag below:

```
<img class="copy_identifier" onclick="getIdentifier('${response.filename}', '${fn:escapeXml(fn:replace(response.distHeadline, "'", "\\'"))}')" src="public/images/hyperlink_13x13.png"></img>
```

Comment: i have the same problem with spring annotation `@Value("#{new Boolean(${mail.util.flag-mock})}")`

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be the single quote is closing the single quote before the ${fn:esca...

You will have to work on handling the quotes better. I have found that creating a function to handle the work is normally easier than doing all this quoting inline.

Comment: I am unable to pass this off to a function to handle.  JavaScript gives me an error when I try to pass a variable with apostrophes in it.

Comment: I was thinking you could escape the xml and replace the quotes before you try to use the value on the page.

Comment: yea i just don't have access to the variables before they come to the page.

Comment: But you can make have several javascript variables that contain the processed values, then use the variables in the getIdentifier call?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <c:set var="print" value="${fn:replace(response.distHeadline,'\\'','& # 9 2 ; & # 3 9 ;')}" />
```

Let me know if print variable gives you the desired output! Let me know how you go about with this!

Comment: Page does not render when I user '\\'', only renders when I user "\\'"